# AssertionError: ERROR: Call to stanford_ie exited with a non-zero code status

Tags: python, unix, sh, stanford-nlp

I am using the python wrapper for Stanford openIE created by philipperemy at here:https://github.com/philipperemy/Stanford-OpenIE-Python. However, I am using a window system so I use Cygwin to run the following code:

```
git clone https://github.com/philipperemy/Stanford-OpenIE-Python.git
cd Stanford-OpenIE-Python
echo "Barack Obama was born in Hawaii." > samples.txt
python main.py -f samples.txt
```

However, I meet the error saying that

```
AssertionError: ERROR: Call to stanford_ie exited with a non-zero code status.
```

I am not sure how to fix it. I used a java version of 1.8.0_121 and I checked if I used the updated version of this Github file by using `$ git pull origin master`.

Does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

To be more specific, the complete error message in here:

```
$ python main.py -f samples.txt
Namespace(filename='samples.txt', generate_graph=False, verbose=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 147, in <module>
exit(main(argv))
File "main.py", line 142, in main
entities_relations = stanford_ie(filename, verbose, generate_graphviz)
File "main.py", line 118, in stanford_ie
assert not java_process.returncode, 'ERROR: Call to stanford_ie exited with a non-zero code status.'
AssertionError: ERROR: Call to stanford_ie exited with a non-zero code status.
```

Comment: You may need to specify a bit more debugging information -- all this says is that the Java process has exited with a nonzero exit code, which could be due to a number of things. But: have you considered using the [CoreNLP server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html), and making REST calls from Python instead?

Comment: Hi @GaborAngeli, I edit my post and add the complete error message I got, could you help me figure out the problem in my code? I am interested in the graph I can get from that package, so that's why I have to use this python wrapper instead of using CoreNLP server and making calls from Python directly.

Comment: Are you running the code in the directory where you've unzipped the OpenIE models? It looks like it expects a classpath of: `stanford-openie.jar:stanford-openie-models.jar:lib/*`, which means all of these files have to exist at the correct relative paths.

Comment: @GaborAngeli, I think I do put the files in the correct path, but the error mesage still exists. Do you think this problem might be due to the operating systems? I am runing this code under windows with Cygwin rather than Unix systems.

Comment: @Vera what does the command "java -version" output?

Answer (score 0):

The straight answer coming from the author of Stanford-OpenIE-Python is that Windows OS is not supported by the library. Details [here](https://github.com/philipperemy/Stanford-OpenIE-Python/issues/4)